# Compare first and second item on the list

Tags: c#, winforms, list

Let's say I'm populating a list with numbers. Every time I press a button a number from textbox get's added to the list.

Now, my questions is: how can I compare the latest item added and second latest item added?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: @SonerGönül What difference does it make? The question is pretty simple, even without code.

Comment: Surely if you're Adding items to the list, the latest and second latest items added will be the last and second last items in the list, not the first and second items...

Comment: I wrote that in the "( )" didn't I? ;)

Comment: Have you considered using a [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) instead?

Comment: I might, since the List<T> is giving me headaches

Comment: @FicVic can you provide more info on logic which you are trying to implement? You should check last added item when you pressing a button? Why you need both last and second last items?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Pressing a button handles two actions: adding number to the list and then comparing that number to the previous added one...I need both last and second last items so that I can compare them.

Comment: @FicVic I added solution, which makes your code mush simpler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` has an indexer property, so why don't you use it?

```
var last = list.Count > 0 ? list[list.Count - 1] : null;
var secondLast = list.Count > 1 ? list[list.Count - 2] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments to question, your task can be simplified if you will do checks before adding item to list:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      var newItem = // get new number

      if (list.Any()) // or list.Count > 0
      {
          var previousItem = list.Last(); // or list[list.Count - 1]
          // compare newItem with previous
      }

      list.Add(newItem);
 };
```